# Error when merging two accounts: A record with these values already exists

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I am trying to merge two accounts and get the following error:

> **Duplicate Record**
>
> A record with these values already exists. A duplicate record cannot be created. Select one or more unique values and try again.

The *Download Log File*-button is greyed out and not clickable.

These accounts can successfully be merged with other accounts, but never with each other. There are no parent or child accounts set on any of the two accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [enabling tracing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeadcrmsupport/archive/2015/05/21/dynamics-crm-tracing.aspx) to be able to debug which SQL statement is failing.

In my case it turned out that there was a Customer Relationship (the kind of pre-2011 Relationship Role which has since been replaced with Connections) created between the two accounts. Deleting the Customer Relationship resulted in the merge succeeding without any issues.